# How to convert json schema draft 7 (elasticsearch api) to swagger 2.0 (outsystems)?

Tags: elasticsearch, swagger, jsonschema, outsystems

I'm trying to consume the Elasticsearch API within Outsystems but the provider and consumer formats mismatch.

Elasticsearch 7.13 defines its API using JSON-Schema draft 7 but Outsystems accepts Swagger 2.0.

Does anyone know any converters that converts JSON Schema 7 to Swagger 2.0.

Or does anyone know how to obtain a Swagger 2.0 version of Elasticsearch API?

[Elasticsearch API](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/rest-api-spec)

[Outsystems](https://success.outsystems.com/Documentation/11/Extensibility_and_Integration/REST/Consume_REST_APIs/Consume_one_or_more_REST_API_methods)

Comment: They are not fully compatible. Any tool claiming to provide such a conversion is not going to be able to handle all cases. Additionally, the format Elasticsearch provide their API in, is not JSON Schema, but a format they have created. They have used JSON Schema to document that format. It looks like a non-standard format, so you can't expect anyone else to use it without writing code.

Comment: Thank you for the information, @Relequestual. This means I'll have to manually create each function in Outsystems or have to write some parser to parse the Elasticsearch documentation of the API into the swagger format.

Comment: Maybe. Does this look helpful https://www.outsystems.com/forge/component-overview/2643/elasticsearch-web ? (I have no idea.) It could be worth contacting outsystems to see if the have a solution to your problem.